# Pull from Github using Git Shell on Windows

Tags: git, github, git-shell

I'm a newbie, so this question might sound really stupid, but what's the command to pull from Git Hub using Git Shell on Windows? Thanks a lot.
I did some research but I don't really understand.

This is what I typed in Git Shell:

```
git pull github.com/A/B.git
```

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started

Answer (score 2):

Do a `git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git`, and then you can do a `git pull` from within the repo on subsequent runs.

Basically, before doing a [pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), the repo has to exist locally and hence you must [clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) it first.

Comment: @user3896999 In future, if you have specific error messages, ask them as part of the question itself, instead of seeking clarifications later. You can go through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how question and answers on SO work.